# type error in function binding

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, primes

I am trying to achieve prime number through recursion, I know how to do it with list.

Type error in function binding

```
primes :: [Int]   
primes = sieve [2..10]   
sieve[] = []   
sieve(x:xs) = x : sieve (filter p [xs])    
   where p x = xs `mod` x > 0
```

I also tried it doing with map and got type error in application

```
primes :: [Int]   
primes = sieve [2..10]   
sieve[] = []   
sieve(x:xs) = x : sieve (map (`mod` x > 0) [xs])
```

I am trying to achieve something similar what we do with list

```
sieve (a:x) = a:sieve [y| y<-x, y`mod`a > 0]
```

Comment: it may be useful to print your code and draw lines on it connecting each variable use site with its definition. That way you will easily discover any shadowing errors you might have, and whether you refer to what you intended to refer to. Also, to note down a var's type near it - it must be the same at both ends of the connecting line, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
xs `mod` x
```

You can't `mod` a list with an integer.

You probably meant

```
where p y = y `mod` x > 0
```

Notice I also had to change the parameter to `y` so it won't shadow the `x` from the pattern on the previous line.

Also, `filter p [xs]` should be `filter p xs`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @hammar I was using the same x instead of using y.